# adding group using python-ldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

i need to add group with several members. so i use this code below

```
import ldap
import ldap.modlist as modlist

# Open a connection
l = ldap.initialize("ldap://localhost:389/")

# Bind/authenticate with a user with apropriate rights to add objects
l.simple_bind_s("cn=manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com","secret")

# The dn of our new entry/object
dn="cn=semuaFK,ou=group,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" 

# A dict to help build the "body" of the object
attrs = {}
attrs['objectclass'] = ['top','groupofnames']
attrs['member'] = 'cn=user1,ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com'
attrs['member'] = 'cn=user2,ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com'
attrs['description'] = 'ini group untuk semua dosen dokter'

# Convert our dict to nice syntax for the add-function using modlist-module
ldif = modlist.addModlist(attrs)

# Do the actual synchronous add-operation to the ldapserver
l.add_s(dn,ldif)

# Its nice to the server to disconnect and free resources when done
l.unbind_s()
```

adding member into group

```
attrs['member'] = 'cn=user1,ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com'
attrs['member'] = 'cn=user2,ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com'
```

but the result is a group with just one member. Only the user2 is added to the group. How to make a group, also add several members to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`member` is a multi-valued attribute (just like `objectClass`). From looking at your code, the problem seems to be that you overwrite the value of the `member` attribute with the 2nd line. The code should be something like this:

```
attrs['member'] = [ 'cn=users1,ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com', 'cn=users2,ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com' ]`
```

or

```
attrs['member'] = [ 'cn=users1,ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com' ]
attrs['member'] += 'cn=users2,ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com'
```